# distance between opposite sides of a Quadrilateral at a given angle

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, geometry-surface

[image]

Hi, I am in need of estimating the distance between the two opposite sides of a quadrilateral as shown in the image. I know the coordinates of P_0, P_1, P_2, P_3 and P_4 points. I need to find the lengths of the "red" and "orange" lines that are orthogonal to each other.  The angle "\alpha" is known as well.

In the past, I dealt with 2D coordinate system, where the there was no z coordinate. I dealt with (a) line equations and (b) intersection of lines concepts to estimate the length of red and orange lines.

However, when it comes to 3D coordinate system, things are same analogy (as in 2D) seems to be tricky. Is there any other way.

I need to program this in FORTRAN.

Thanks in advance.

**Edits summary:**

Edit1: Yes, All the points (P0 through P4) are co-planar i.e. form a quadrilateral plane. The red and the orange lines also lie in the quadrilateral plane. However, this quadrilateral plane is oriented in a 3D space.

Comment: Do you know if the four points are coplanar? If they are, you could transform everything into 2D space, based on that plane.

Comment: In general, 3D lines do not intersect. Do you have any guarantee that they do ? Is the problem planar ?

Comment: "things are same analogy (as in 2D) seems to be tricky": what ??

Comment: @aptriangle :
I have revised my question with "Edits summary:". Yes they are coplanar. Could you let explain a bit more on "transform everything into 2D space" ?

Comment: Use a change of basis that brings XY coplanar with the quadrilateral and drop Z.

Comment: @YvesDaoust In 2D system, I don't have a z coordinate. So, I used linear equations such as y=mx+c and I could calculate the intersection points between red/orange lines with blue lines.

In 3D, I came had to account for z coordinates. Eventually, I can't eliminate the z coordinate and hence, I couldn't use y = mx+c.  Though I see that everything lie in the same plane.  But I couldn't figure out a way to do it.

Comment: That's why you need to drop Z. Lookup change of basis.

Comment: A clarification:
In short I should be transforming the 3D co-planar plane points with normal (n1,n2,n3) into 2D co-planar (0,0,n3)? 
It turns out to be finding the rotation matrix and applying the rotation to all the points (P0 through P4).

Comment: As the problem is affine-invariant, any change of basis can do.

Comment: I tried this as a first attempt, found to be simple :[link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213285/calculating-plane-rotation-angles)
@YvesDaoust 
1. I tried to bring my plane with normal (n1,n2,n3) to z axix, I assumed to use (n1,n2,n3) = (cosθ sinϕ, sinθsinϕ, cosϕ). where I need to make a rotation about y-axis by θ, followed by a rotation about the z-axis by ϕ. where  ϕ = arccos(n3), θ=arctan(n2/n1). However, it didn't work. Am i doing some mistake?

Comment: @YvesDaoust  
 I tried this as a second attempt using rotation matrix: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167717/transform-a-plane-to-the-xy-plane/1167779#1167779)

I found the quadrilateral equation from points P1-P4 and translated the points in z direction to have ax+by+cz=0 as my quadrilateral.  Estimated cos(theta),sin(theta), u1, u2 and rotational matrix.

Checked [R]{P1}, [R]{P2}, [R]{P3} [R]{P4} are not having same z-coordinate after rotation. 

Eventually, both methods didn't work for me to make this 3D quadrilateral to 2D quadrilateral.

Comment: I suggested a change of basis.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I started with reading change of basis. Unfortunately, I couldn't follow the concepts and found it difficult as it is new to me.

Instead, I worked on the methodology given in second method [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167717/transform-a-plane-to-the-xy-plane/4488593#4488593)  and figure out the correct way. Updated my method as an answer to the same post.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the result on 2D case, it is better to transform this problem into that case by using the transformation P(x,y,z) --> P(x/z, y/z, 1). It can be seen as the projection this plan into the plane z = 1. You also need to think about the case one z_i = 0; so if(z_i == 0)( z_i + = 1) then redo the previous process. In the case of 2D, we only need a function calculate the intersection between two lines and a distance function. I know that this is better to be in comment section but I dont have enough reputation to add a comment, I am new in this group. Sorry!

Comment: Please improve your formatting and remove the last line.